# This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Express js MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cookies

**Here I am checking for session**

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
      if (req.cookies.user_sid && !req.session.user) {
        res.clearCookie("user_sid");
      }
      next();
    });
```

I don't know why I am getting error too many redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this work....

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.user) {
         res.clearCookie("user_sid");
    }
    next();
});
```